# ClearQuest 8 upgrade restoring schema and db

Tags: clearcase, clearquest

I'm trying to upgrade clearquest server 7.1.x.x to 8.x.x
I'm uninstalling 7.1.x.x and installing the version 8.

After upgradation how can i restore the connections that CQ had to schema repository and user DB?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, The simplest way is to:

1. Open the ClearQuest Maintenance Tool
2. Select the profile you want to keep.
3. Select File/Export profile.

If the host is Unix, you should look for a directory in the clearquest install directory with one of these names:

- cqdb_rgy
- CQDB_rgys
- cqdb_registry

Archive that directory and put it back when you have finished the upgrade. The Installation Manager upgrade process may do this for you.